# want to set exception for twilio

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, twilio

i am sending otp using twilio,laravel, message is working now, but i want to set exception for if message is not delivered etc i have tried like

```
 public function send_otp()
{

    try {
            $account_sid = env('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'); 
            $auth_token = env('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'); 
            $number=Auth::user()->user_phone;
            $client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token); 
            $messages = $client->messages->create($number, array( 
                 'From' => '+12533368077',
                 'Body' => Auth::user()->user_otp,
            ));
                dd($messages);
                //return $messages;
        //throw new Exception();

  }  catch (Exception $e) {

         return response()->json(['error' => true,'message'=>'Something went wrong'],200);
 }

}
```

can you please help me with this

Comment: have you imported the global exception? (`use Exception;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting `env` data did you clear cache?

```
php artisan config:cache
```

If you want to handle error - laravel has special logic for that. You need to just to catch that error and then make action, it is simple:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof CustomException) {
        return response()->view('errors.custom', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: yes my message is sending fine but i want to handle exception if in future, if any number wont get message fot that

Comment: look now at answer